# Opencart Rest API to get various information

Tags: api, opencart

Is it possible to get new `order information`, `product information`, `customer information` etc from Opencart Rest API? If possible, how. Please help me...

Comment: refer to this: `http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/system/users/api/`